# How to repair a damaged .doc (word) file

Tags: document, word-documents

(This is Lubuntu 13.04)

I have a damaged .doc (word) file, made with abiword. The power went off, and damaged the file. I tried reading it in libreoffice as well. Any advice on how repairing this file on Ubuntu?

Comment: what happens when you try to open it with libreoffice? is there any recovery screen?

Comment: This is what libreoffice says:  File format error found at 151,163 (row, col).   Now file recovery dialog opens!

Comment: Did you try using the recovery dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to salvage some of the text. Try running this command in a terminal:

```
strings foo.doc > output.txt
```

Then open `output.txt` in a text editor to see the results. (Note that this particular command will only work with `.doc` files, and not the newer `.docx` format.)

To filter only strings of at least ten characters:

```
strings -n10 foo.doc > output.txt
```

Comment: `strings foo.doc > bar.doc` to output all in a doc. http://askubuntu.com/a/589399/47206. `less` may not be good when a lot of useful text recovered is separated into short lines of 5-6 characters

Comment: @cipricus: Good point, thanks! I've updated the answer for future visitors.

Comment: But the files are zip compressed.. i think its better to remove the compression first...

Comment: @777Anon: As I mentioned, this question is about `.doc` files, which are not compressed. The newer `.docx` files are compressed XML which can probably be read in a text editor without `strings`.