# How to copy and paste all text recovered in Terminal with `strings` command?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, gnome-terminal, document

I want to recover text from a .doc file that wouldn't open in any text editors (msoffice word, libreoffice writer).

I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/294565/47206) saying to use a command like

```
strings foo.doc | less
```

And it seems that a lot of the text is in this way visible in terminal.

But while I am trying to copy/paste, only what is in the actual terminal window is copied - that is less than a page.

How to select and copy all the text accessed in terminal?

Comment: Save the output to another file `strings foo.doc > new_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strings` will print only the printable characters in a file. To get what you want you just need to save the output of `strings` to another file and then read the new file in the usual manner. Here is the way:

```
strings foo.doc > bar.doc
```

Now `bar.doc` will contain the strings having printable characters from `foo.doc`.

Comment: @cipricus: No problem, although i had this commented first, the important thing is the problem is resolved. Also note that you don't need `less` as mentioned in the other answer. So, `strings foo.doc > output.txt` will do.

Comment: `less` was not good in the given case anyway because a lot of useful text recovered was separated into short lines of 5-6 characters